# accum<int>(&name[0], &name[length]) gives error cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'const int *'

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
inline
T accum (T const* beg, T const* end)
{
    T total = T();  // assume T() actually creates a zero value
    while (beg != end) {
        total += *beg;
        ++beg;
    }
    return total;
}

int main() 
{ 

// create array of 5 integer values 
int num[]={1,2,3,4,5}; 

// print average value 
std::cout << "the average value of the integer values is " 
          << accum(&num[0], &num[5]) / 5 
          << '\n'; 

// create array of character values 
char name[] = "templates"; 
int length = sizeof(name)-1; 

// (try to) print average character value 
std::cout << "the average value of the characters in \"" 
          << name << "\" is " 
          << accum(&name[0], &name[length]) / length 
          //<< accum<int>(&name[0], &name[length]) / length //but this give me error
          << '\n'; 
}
```

I was reading c++ templates:the complete guide book and the author mentioned
that I can use template specialization
`accum<int>(&name[0], &name[length]) / length`
I try this in visual studio 2012 and got error
main.cpp(34): error C2664: 'accum' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'const int *'
My C++ is a bit rusty.
I'm just curious, if this "behavior" previously allowed but there's changes in "latest" C++ standard making this illegal or this is an error on the book I'm reading.

Comment: While experimenting yourself, you should also look into the already existing functions, like [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: Perhaps you are misreading what is in the book, or did you mean `accum<char>(&name[0], &name[length])`?

Comment: This is not what the book says. The section shows you how to use traits, thus has the form `template <typename T> typename AccumulationTraits<T>::AccT accum(T const* begin, T const* end)`

Comment: quote from the book(literally copy and paste):The problem here is that our template was instantiated for the type char, which turns out to be too by introducing an additional template parameter AccT that describes the type used for the variable total (and hence the return type). However, this would put an extra burden on all users of our template: They would have to specify an extra type in every invocation of our template. In our example we may, therefore, need to write the following:

accum<int>(&name[0],&name[length]) 
This is not an excessive constraint, but it can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instantiation is `int accum<int> (int const* beg, int const* end)`, you can't pass `char *` arguments to this function.

The reason the uncommented line works is that it instantiates `accum<char>`.

Comment: No, at least from 1995 or so :)

Comment: I just delete my earlier comment above but just for the record I'm asking if the code work in the past.Thanks, it's really turn me upside down when the book I'm reading suggest correct solution but error when testing it out...hence the question whether the book is outdated or just error on the book author part.

Comment: @kypronite The book **is** correct. You haven't read it carefully enough. It specifically says "... we could resolve this by *introducing an additional template parameter AccT* that describes the type used for the variable total (and hence the return type)". That is, a new function of the form template `<typename T, typename Ret> Ret accum(T const* begin, T const* end)`

Comment: @Yuushi Just a minor correction: it would actually have to be `template <typename Ret, typename T> Ret accum(T const* begin, T const* end)`, so that `Ret` can be specified and `T` can still be deduced.

Comment: @Angew Thanks, typed that out quickly without thinking. You're right, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The line `accum<int>(&name[0], &name[length])` tries to call a function declared `int accumt(const int*, const int*)` with arguments of type `char*, char*`. The compiler is right to complain: C++ never allowed implicit conversions from `char*` to `int*`. If that is what the book says, there's an error in it.